# Javascript document.replaceElement() optimization

Tags: javascript, replace, element

Today i got the problem to reset my `<input type="file">` after uploading with XmlHttpRequest. After some search for a solution i only found jQuery related stuff, but i rather want to implement it in pure Javascript (learning). So i created a function for it, named `document.replaceElement`, and the alias functions `document.replaceElementById` and `document.replaceElementsByTagName`.

I want to share this functions, and my question is now: *How to optimize them?* I'm not a freak as some others out there, so if someone can help optimizing them, try out. I'm really interested in it.

*Please to not refer to a jQuery again, i wont use it, and i know how to make this possible with jQuery...*

**THANK YOU**

## The Javascript (replace-element.js)

```
// define replaceElement
// param E = element to replace
// param N = replace with this element
//           if not given (undefined), recreate the one from the dom!
//           if empty replace with empty text node
//           if given string replace with innerHTML of string
//           if given as array or nodeList, replace with the full list
// param R = used to return the new element instead of replace E
//           primarily used for recursive call
document.replaceElement = function(E,N,R) {
  // check if given plain string
  if (typeof N == 'string') {
    // in case of string use innerHTML on a new Element (used <p> here)
    var X = document.createElement('p');
    X.innerHTML = N;
    // if multiple elements are inserted, check all the nodes and push
    // them to N, which will laterly be inserted using insertBefore
    var S = X.firstChild;
    if (S != null) {
      N = [];
    }
    while (S != null) {
      if (S.nodeType == 1) {
        N.push(S);
      }
      S = S.nextSibling;
    }
    // if theres only one element, there is no need to use as array
    if (N.length && N.length == 1) {
      N = N[0];
    }
  }
  // if the given replace-to value (see N parameter) is not given
  // lookup the dom and recreate the element with its originial contents
  else if (!N) {
    // checked for elements itself here...
    if (E.nodeType == 1) {
      // create new element
      N = document.createElement(E.nodeName);
      // i needed to walk through all the attributed on the given element
      // and push them to the attributes of the new element
      for(var i = 0;i < E.attributes.length;i++) {
        // some struggling here with .value and .nodeValue, as well as setAttribute
        // and setAttributeNode here, because of different js versions
        if (typeof N.setAttribute !== undefined) {
          if (E.attributes[i].value) {
            N.setAttribute(E.attributes[i].nodeName,E.attributes[i].value);
          } else {
            N.setAttribute(E.attributes[i].nodeName,E.attributes[i].nodeValue);
          }
        } else {
          N.setAttributeNode(E.attributes[i].cloneNode(false));
        }
      }
      // now walk the given elements child list and append them
      // to the element using recursive calls for creation
      var S = E.firstChild;
      while (S != null) {
        N.appendChild(document.replaceElement(S,undefined,true));
        S = S.nextSibling;
      }
    }
    // got some errors here, so text nodes are also checked
    // and inserted with createTextNode. TODO: use .data here?
    else if (E.nodeType == 3) {
      N = document.createTextNode(E.nodeValue);
    }
    // all other types of elements are cloned directly
    else {
      N = E.cloneNode(true);
    }
  }
  // check if this is not an recursive call...
  if (!R) {
    // if the new element has length, it is a nodeList or array!
    // walking that and use insertBefore on the parent node
    if (N.length !== undefined) {
      for (i=0;i<N.length;i++) {
        E.parentNode.insertBefore(N[i],E);
      }
      // the original element is deleted if empty string given
      E.parentNode.removeChild(E);
    } else {
      // the given element is replaced with the new one using replaceChild...
      E.parentNode.replaceChild(N,E);
    }
  }
  return N;
}
// simple *ById implementation for replaceElement
document.replaceElementById = function(E,C) {
  return document.replaceElement(document.getElementById(E),C);
}
// another simple *ByName for replaceElement
document.replaceElementsByName = function(E,C) {
  E = document.getElementsByName(E);
  var Z = [];
  for (var i=0;i<E.length;i++) {
    Z.push(document.replaceElement(E[i],C));
  }
  return Z;
}
```

## HTML Code (replace-element.html)

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test replaceElement</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="replace-element.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="my-div" name="named-div">
<input type="file" id="my-button" name="named-button" multiple="true" />
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="type in text" />
</div>

<br /><br />
<button onclick="document.replaceElementById('my-button')">replace BUTTON by id</button>
<button onclick="document.replaceElementsByName('named-button')">replace BUTTON by name</button>

<br /><br />
<button onclick="document.replaceElementById('my-div')">replace DIV by id</button>
<button onclick="document.replaceElementsByName('named-div')">replace DIV by name</button>

<br /><br />
<button onclick="document.replaceElementById('my-div','<p>YES, <strong>REPLACED</strong>!</p>')">replace DIV by p tag</button>
<button onclick="document.replaceElementsByName('named-div','<p>YES, <strong>REPLACED</strong>!</p>')">replace DIV by p tag</button>

<br /><br />
<button onclick="document.replaceElementById('my-button','')">delete BUTTON by id</button>
<button onclick="document.replaceElementsByName('named-button','')">delete BUTTON by name</button>
<button onclick="document.replaceElementById('my-div','')">delete DIV by id</button>
<button onclick="document.replaceElementsByName('named-div','')">delete DIV by name</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One letter variable names make the code too hard to read.  Not even comments telling what they are or what they do.  Too much dense code to try to decipher.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher: Added comments, thanks for this. I will update the code using more precise variable names later... :-)